# FlexORM self referencing

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I wonder if there is someone out there that had used the framework called FlexORM, is pretty useful, but I'm having a problem, I need to create a self referencing association for a parent with children table like this

a table called table1 that has a field called parentID which has the value of some table1 ID, make sense?

the problem is that I have no idea how structure the class with the annotation or if even possible to do it with this framework, I know that in other technologies like Doctrine for example if very simple to do it like here

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing

I had tried any kind of combinations but without result, any help of this will be vere appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was little hard to find cause the pages aren't visible anymore, anyways here is what I was trying to

http://flexorm.riaforge.org/wiki/index.cfm/Tree_Structures

thanks!